# Sympy printing how to keep e as e and not as numbers

Tags: sympy

A formula like this

$$e^{-\lambda x}\sqrt{\lambda}$$

Actually shows up like this in sympym, where the e shows up as the float 2.718....

[image]

Is there a way to keep this constant as e and not as the float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use mpmath's e, use SymPy's: `from sympy import E` and then `T = l*E**(-l*x)`